# Rename [route53] to [amazon-route53]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

All the other tags that fall under the Amazon Web Services umbrella follow the convention of starting with 'amazon-', this appears to be the only remaining exception.

As per [Amazon's description](http://aws.amazon.com/products/):

> Amazon Route 53 is a highly available and scalable Domain Name System
>   (DNS) web service.

One possible argument for leaving the tag would be that Route 53 is viable as a stand alone service (unlike something like amazon-ebs which cannot be used without amazon-ec2). In this case, I would suggest that amazon-route53 should at least be a synonym.

[route53](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/route53) should be renamed to [amazon-route53](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-route53)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. Since it's a vendor specific name the tag should have *Amazon* in its title – like all other Amazon tags.

So I've renamed [route53](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/route53) to [amazon-route53](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-route53) and defined a synonym.